# Installation of a software in .csh environment

Tags: linux, csh, configure

I am trying to install a software called [Plumed](http://www.plumed.org/) on HPC environment, which is csh based. I have successfully done installation in bash environment. Typically in bash environment, following command is used to configure:

```
./configure --prefix=/home1/GroupAN/kirtika/softwares/plumed/ CC=/home1/GroupAN/kirtika/libraries/bin/mpicc CXX=/home1/GroupAN/kirtika/libraries/bin/mpicxx FC=/home1/GroupAN/kirtika/libraries/bin/mpifort
```

I tried this for csh environment :

```
setenv mpicc /opt/mvapich2-1.8/intel/bin/mpicc
setenv mpicxx /opt/mvapich2-1.8/intel/bin/mpicxx
setenv mpifort /opt/mvapich2-1.8/intel/bin/mpifort
setenv plumedir /home1/GroupAN/kirtika/softwares/plumed/

./configure --prefix=$plumedir CC=$mpicc CXX=$mpicxx FC=$mpifort
```

It didn't work. Error was :

```
configure: error: in `/home/phd/16/mbukirt/plumed-2.2.3':
configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables  [1]: http://www.plumed.org/
```

If someone can help me with this that will be great. Also, How these lines can be configured for csh environment ? I can think of only changing `export` to `setenv`

```
export PATH="/home/phd/16/mbukirt/plumed-2.2.3/src/lib/:$PATH"
export LIBRARY_PATH="/home/phd/16/mbukirt/plumed-2.2.3/src/lib/:$LIBRARY_PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/phd/16/mbukirt/plumed-2.2.3/src/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/phd/16/mbukirt/plumed-2.2.3/src/lib/:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export PLUMED_KERNEL="/home/phd/16/mbukirt/plumed-2.2.3/src/lib/libplumedKernel.so"
```

Comment: You set `mpicc` twice, and then use the undefined variable `mpicxx` on the `configure` command line...

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I will correct it.

Comment: One has to have a look at the `config`log file to figure out what went wrong. If you put it up on pastebin.com (for example), it would be easier to debug. Update the question with a link to the `config.log` file.

Comment: @Kusalananda    [link](http://pastebin.com/yT3g6ckr)

Comment: So the real error is `/opt/mvapich2-1.8/intel/bin/mpicxx: line 273: icpc: command not found`.  You should talk to an admin of the system. The `mpicxx` compiler wrapper is not finding the real underlying compiler (`icpc`).

Comment: @Kusalananda Yeah. I got it too. It's working fine. Thank you. Could you help with the second thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual error here is hidden in the `config.log` file.

The MPI compilers `mpicc` and `mpicxx` (for C and C++ respectively) are actually "wrappers" around real compilers.  What the wrappers do is calling the compiler with the appropriate flags.

It seems as if the `mpicxx` compiler wrapper is not finding the `icpc` compiler (which is the Intel C++ compiler).  In the `config.log` this is shown as

```
/opt/mvapich2-1.8/intel/bin/mpicxx: line 273: icpc: command not found
```

To solve this, contact an admin of the system to see whether this is a misconfiguration of the MPI installation, or whether you have missed loading some sort of software module.

As for the second part of the question,

The `sh`-style `export` command

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/phd/16/mbukirt/plumed-2.2.3/src/lib/:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

may be written using `setenv` as

```
setenv DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH "/home/phd/16/mbukirt/plumed-2.2.3/src/lib/:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

in `csh` (and similarly for the other lines of `export` commands). Note the omission of any `=`.